# Calculating weekly data from a range of dates

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, select, group-by

I have a date range lets say from `2012-12-01` and `2013-01-09`. I want to fetch weekly data for number of records, it should be 7 days from the start date for each week.So `2012-12-01` to `2012-12-07` is `week1` and so on...

The table is as below,

```
+-ID-+--items---+---dated---+
+----+----------+-----------+
| 1  | 10       |2012-12-01 |
| 2  | 2        |2012-12-02 |
| .  | .        |   .       |
| .  | .        |   .       |
| .  | .        |   .       |
+----+----------+-----------+
```

Initial query  `Select count(items),week(date) from item_data`

Answer (score 1):

Try this ...

```
SELECT `id`, `items`, `dated`
FROM `table` 
GROUP BY WEEK(`dated`)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(items) AS total_items, CONCAT(dated, ' - ', dated + INTERVAL 6 DAY) AS week
    FROM tablename
    GROUP BY WEEK(dated)
    ORDER BY WEEK(dated);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT CEILING(DATEDIFF(dated, '2012-12-01')) AS weekNo, SUM(items) AS NoOfItems
FROM table
WHERE dated BETWEEN '2012-12-01' AND '2013-01-09'
GROUP BY weekNo
```